# Assign to an unknown generic out-parameter when implementing INumberBase

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement the relative new [INumberBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1?view=net-7.0) interface for a custom number type, let's call it `BigFloat`.

One of the functions that I need to implement has the following signature:

```
static bool INumberBase<BigFloat>.TryConvertToTruncating<TOther>(BigFloat value, out TOther result) where TOther : System.Numerics.INumberBase<TOther>
```

This function is meant for conversion to other number types, such as `float`, `double`, and `int`. I have functions to convert to each of these types.

How do I implement the function above? In principle, I'd want to assign to the `result` out-parameter a value that depends on its type.

I am imagining that it would look something like the below pseudocode:

```
static bool INumberBase<BigFloat>.TryConvertToTruncating<TOther>(BigFloat value, out TOther result) {
    if (result is float) {
         result = value.ToFloat();
         return true;
    }
    if (result is double) {
         result = value.ToDouble();
         return true;
    }
    if (result is int) {
         result = value.ToInt();
         return true;
    }
    // Must assign out-parameter even if conversion is not supported.
    result = TOther.Zero;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try implementing your pseudo code? Did you get any issues?

Comment: `TryX` methods should not throw exceptions, thus you may need to handle any issues when converting and return `false`.

Comment: @Orifjon "Cannot implicitly convert float to TOther" on assignment.

Comment: I don't throw exceptions on those conversion functions, so that's ok. Another problem is that the compiler wants me to assign to the out-parameter even if I don't support the conversion to that type (which is supposed to be denoted by returning false). That I can actually solve by additional `result = TOther.Zero;`.

Comment: Try instead of `result is float` using `typeof(TOther) == typeof(float)` or something equivalent.

Comment: It seems I can solve the assignment problem by `result = TOther.CreateTruncating(value.ToFloat());` and so on. Then there is still `Use of unassigned out parameter result.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is basically correct. You write a check for each of the number types that you support, and convert to that type.

```
static bool INumberBase<BigFloat>.TryConvertToTruncating<TOther>(BigFloat value, out TOther result) {
    if (typeof(TOther) == typeof(float)) {
         result = (TOther)(object)value.ToFloat();
         return true;
    }
    if (typeof(TOther) == typeof(double)) {
         result = (TOther)(object)value.ToDouble();
         return true;
    }
    if (typeof(TOther) == typeof(int)) {
         result = (TOther)(object)value.ToInt();
         return true;
    }
    result = TOther.Zero;
    return false;
}
```

I suppose the key here is that you need to cast to `object` first before casting to `TOther`.

See also [how `BigInteger` implements this](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,4832).

Comment: _"I suppose the key here is that you need to cast to `object` first before casting to `TOther`."_ - doing that would require the runtime to box and unbox a value-type, which will ruin performance. Fortunately there are ways to do this without boxing+unboxing (often involving `IL.Emit`) but it's disappointing that `BigInteger` doesn't seem to do that... I feel I should submit a PR or something now...

Comment: @Dai Would `TOther.CreateTruncating(value.ToFloat())` be better than `(TOther)(object)value.ToFloat()`?

Comment: @Sweeper That `BigInteger` code is great find. They seem to be assigning `default` rather than `TOther.Zero` on the unsupported types, but not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: @kaba I don't know, I'm not yet familiar with the new `INumber...` types (my day-job is stuck on .NET 4.8 and Core 3.1 still, I only get to use .NET 7+ for smaller projects)

Comment: @Sweeper It means the same thing, just dotnet ecosystem community shorthand

Comment: @kaba [The default implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Numerics/INumberBase.cs,106) of `CreateTruncating` still has the cast, so probably not

Comment: @Dai Ah I see. I thought `ILGenerator.Emit` is for generating new types and methods dynamically, not for adding code to an existing method. Do you mean they should generate the `BigInteger` struct using `System.Reflection.Emit` APIs, instead hand-write the code for it?

Comment: @Sweeper Good to know.

Comment: @Sweeper It's a tad more complicated than that - what you'd have is a "normal" public type with public methods (either the type or method would be generic over `T`) which would directly invoke a `static readonly Func<> _innerMethodImpl = MyMethodFactory.CreateMyInnerMethod()` - where `CreateMyInnerMethod` does the IL-emit logic to handle `T` specifically - basically like C++ template specialization, but wired-up at runtime because you can't do it at compile-time. So Emit is only used for generating methods, not entire types. (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: @Dai I see. I never thought of putting the generated method into a delegate!

Comment: @Sweeper Here's a real-life example from my personal library that implements high-performance, nonboxing, operations over enum types regardless of their underlying integer type: https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/aa07ceda23b2ca03184722c3f63ce7ca